# Angular - how to land always on the start page when refreshing the browser from a secondary route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a simple scenario. My app starts with a default component, let's say **StartComponent**, which is reached via Angular router using a route named **start**. So in the browser bar I see something like `myhost/start`.

The logic of the app then brings me to a second component, **SecondComponent**, when I navigate to the route named **second**, so in the browser bar I see `myhost/second`.

If now I do a refresh of the browser, e.g. via ***Command-R*** or ***Ctrl-F5***, I land again on **SecondComponent**.

What I would like to see happen though is that the refresh of the browser brings me again to **StartComponent** regardless of where I do the refresh from.

Which is the cleanest way to reach this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried adding router navigation to your AppComponent's ngOnInit? It only runs once at app startup.

Comment: I am using the Angular router so I do not think that AppComponent's ngOnInit can solve my problem

Comment: You can inject the router into your AppComponent and call navigateByUrl in ngOnInit. That way, on every startup, the router will navigate to the route you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the same strategy as redirecting to a login if the user isn't logged in. You can use a `CanActivate` which performs a router redirect, but doesn't block the route change (i.e. it always resolves to `true`).

```
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateStart implements CanActivate {
    public constructor(private _router: Router) {

    }

    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if(!(route.component instanceof StartComponent)) {
           this._router.navigateByUrl('/start'); 
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

It might look strange to always return `true`, but if you return `false` it cancels the route change and at the sametime blocks the `navigateByUrl()`.

Place this at the top level of the router configuration, and it will only be executed once. When the browser is refreshed it will trigger the redirect.

```js
const routes = [
     {
        canActivate: [CanActivateStart],
        children: [
           // the routes you want to force a redirect
        ]
     }, {....}
]
```

Comment: I’m touch lost on *Place this at the top level of the router configuration*. Could you add what this would look like?

Comment: @AndrewAllen I updated my answer. Basically you want to apply the can activate to a parent route, but make sure the start component is one of the children. Otherwise you'll be in an infinite loop.

Comment: @AndrewAllen now that I think about it this might not work.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I've never done `route.component` as a condition in can activate. There is a chance that start might not be set when this is run and it'll infinite loop. You might have to play with this a little and maybe just check the current URL via the router.

Comment: @Reactgular note that using `route.component instanceof StartComponent` is not reliable, because of obfuscation/minification when production build is created. Instead, I would suggest adding static property `id` to every component which should be comparable. Then you would comapre it like: `route.component.id === StartComponent.id`

Comment: @Michal that's not true at all. Minification will never affect the use of `instanceof`. It just gets rewritten to something like `route.component instanceof AE` but the variable `AE` is still the same constructor function.

Comment: @Reactgular that's what I was expecting, but from my recent experience, I had to go with a different approach. I haven't tested it with the latest angular, but the project was not set up with an obsolete version of angular either.

Comment: @Reactgular the strategy of using a CanActivate actually worked. My logic was a little bit more complex than what I described in the question so I ended up having a slightly more complicated if, but anyways it worked.

Comment: But this would redirect back to home even if you try to navigate trough the app xD